# Is it possible to set up a functioning "contact us" page using HTML/CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering if it's possible to set up a functioning "contact us" page using HTML/CSS. For example, a user can go to the "contact" page and input their email address and message to me, and I will receive their message in my email. Can you do this with just html/css? if so what would that be called? Or will have I have to use some JavaScript?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, this is more of a general question. I have a friend who wants me to build them a website, but only using HTML/CSS as they don't know much code and it will be easier for them to maintain on their own after. I usually use Rails for everything and know how to do it in Rails, but I'm wondering if it's possible with just HTML/CSS.

Comment: Until they don't change fields name in form, it should not be a problem posting them even if they change design and so.

Answer (score 1):

You can only using a postprocessor (like posting form elements to php,  using REST or other method reflected on server-side) or an inline script(call it javascript, jquery, ajax, the name doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use JavaScript to Just reading the values in your input fields. then you can use the mailto action

Refer : [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_mailto)

Another way is use the Ajax calls to send the data to a php file and then send it to your inbox using php mail function

Reference for Ajax : [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp)